# laravel/homestead vboxmanage import no last argument

Tags: laravel, import, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm really new in laravel and I'm just fixing the environment. I've followed the instructions in https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead until 'Launching The Vagrant Box'

when I run 'vagrant up' or 'homestead up' I'm running into this error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "-n", ""]

Stderr: Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 5.0.12
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage import           <ovfname/ovaname>
                        [--dry-run|-n]
                        [--options keepallmacs|keepnatmacs|importtovdi]
                        [more options]
                        (run with -n to have options displayed
                         for a particular OVF)


Syntax error: Not enough arguments for "import" command.
```

my homestead.yaml is:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox


authorize: c:/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:/Users/Mr/.ssh/id_rsa/

folders:
    - map: c:/Users/Me/Desktop/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/homestead/public
      hhvm: true
databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I've tried the git method and the composer method. I've been at this for a week. my computer supports vms. I've checked. Help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. I should've used the git bash instead the cmd.